# SQL Stored Procedure: Using column name in cursor

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

Want to read values from one table and update second table with result of an aggregate function. Given is origin table like this:

```
lfnr    WertA    WertB    WertC
1      1       1       2
2      100     100     200
3      NULL    1       NULL
40     NULL    1       NULL
5      1       NULL    1
6      0       0       0
NULL   NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Second table:

```
  CREATE TABLE table_2
(
CPOINT varchar(10),
RESULT float
);
INSERT INTO table_2 VALUES('WertA', 0)
INSERT INTO table_2 VALUES('WertB', 0)
INSERT INTO table_2 VALUES('WertC', 0)
```

Now I have a stored procedure to update table_2:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_result_top]
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @resultA float
    DECLARE @resultB float
    DECLARE @resultC float

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

        SET @resultA = 
        (SELECT AVG(CAST(s1 AS float)) FROM (SELECT TOP 3 WertA s1 
        FROM synta_rollmw WHERE WertA IS NOT NULL ORDER BY lfnr DESC)u);

        SET @resultB = 
        (SELECT AVG(CAST(s1 AS float)) FROM (SELECT TOP 3 WertB s1 
        FROM synta_rollmw WHERE WertB IS NOT NULL ORDER BY lfnr DESC)u);

        SET @resultC = 
        (SELECT AVG(CAST(s1 AS float)) FROM (SELECT TOP 3 WertC s1 
        FROM synta_rollmw WHERE WertC IS NOT NULL ORDER BY lfnr DESC)u);

        UPDATE table_2 SET RESULT=@resultA WHERE CPOINT='WertA'
        UPDATE table_2 SET RESULT=@resultB WHERE CPOINT='WertB'
        UPDATE table_2 SET RESULT=@resultC WHERE CPOINT='WertC'
END
```

This works but is not really nice. My approach ist to use a cursor, reading values from column cpoint and use this in statement:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_result_top_cursor]
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @result float
    -- Variable for Cursor
    DECLARE @cpoint CHAR(10)
    -- define Cursor
    DECLARE C1 CURSOR READ_ONLY FOR SELECT cpoint FROM table_2

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    OPEN C1
    FETCH NEXT FROM C1 INTO @cpoint
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @result = 
        (SELECT AVG(CAST(s1 AS float)) FROM (SELECT TOP 3 @cpoint s1 
        FROM synta_rollmw WHERE @cpoint IS NOT NULL ORDER BY lfnr DESC)u)

        UPDATE table_2 SET RESULT=@result WHERE CPOINT=@cpoint
        FETCH NEXT FROM C1 INTO @cpoint
    END
    CLOSE C1
    DEALLOCATE C1
END
```

I can create the procedure but trying to execute gives me an error on converting varchar to int. I think my fault (again) is the usage of variable @cpoint. Can this be solved? Thanks!

Comment: you can't use a column name as variable name. You must use (if your DBMS is Sql Server) a dynamic SQL

Comment: what you want to do is called "unrolling" - do a search for this term on this site, or google-search for this, there are numerous variations of the problem. there is even a DTSX unrolling-task, maybe its worthwhile to read its documentation